# The intersection of comeager sets in a Baire Space

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

Is it true that in a Baire Space the intersection of two comeager sets is not empty? If yes, is the intersection comeager too?

Comment: Think to the readers. Give the definitions of a Baire space and of a co-meagre set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both are true, because the union of countably many meagre sets is meagre: it’s still the union of countably many nowhere dense sets.

Comment: sorry for you countable union means a countably infinite union or also a finite union? I mean, if I assume that in the Baire theorem he means countably infinite, is the theorem true also for finite union/intersections?

Comment: @Richard: Finite or countably infinite. This is also the meaning in the Baire category theorem, and in fact the usual meaning in mathematics.